# JSON ParseError even though request was successful

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, http-headers, coffeescript

I am getting a JSON parseerror even though the return from the server was successful. Here is my save code where fail() is always being run

```
@model.save()
  .fail(=> @resetForm() )
  .always (obj, error) ->
    console.log obj
    console.log obj.responseText
    console.log JSON.parse(obj.responseText)
```

Here is my error object:

```
"parsererror"
"No conversion from text to http://api2.local/users/auth"
```

## Some notes:

I am on Jquery 1.8.3 and Backbone 0.9.9
The server responds correctly with json - here is my response header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:origin, x-requested-with, content-type, accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:86400
Connection:Keep-Alive 
Content-Length:202
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 21 Dec 2012 18:46:25 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server: xxx
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.1
```

console.log JSON.parse(obj.responseText) correctly gives me a JSON object

### EDIT: Request Headers

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:54
Content-Type:application/json
Host:api2.local
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:3000/login
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.101 Safari/537.11
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

### EDIT: Request Payload via POST

```
{"email":"x@x.com","password":"xxx"}
```

### EDIT: Response Payload

```
{
"user_id":"xx",
"first_name":"xxx",
"last_name":"xxx",
"email":"x@x.com",
"role":"xxxx",
"date_joined":"xxx"
}
```

Comment: What does the request look like? Especially the headers, ...

Comment: If you are getting the correct JSON object,it is obviously not a JSON parse error.

Comment: added request header above - yea its parsing correctly thats why I'm so confused

Comment: Do you think it could be an authorization/login issue? Have you authenticated with your server?

Comment: That's not a JSON parse error, that error is from jQuery's automatic data type conversion. See [relevant source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/e63625e16e0e337d2ddafd6b46313434dfae3f84/src/ajax.js#L834).

Comment: ic - so basically, the response from the server is saying its json but its not? and thats giving me the type conversion error?

Comment: @imrane not really, something seems to have gone wrong in the jQuery conversion -- it should never try to convert from `text` to a URL. I don't now how that would happen. Perhaps the response is wrong somehow. Could you post the request and response bodies as well?

Comment: @LinusGThiel - sorry for the delay - was in transit - the request / response is simple JSON so I don't know if thats the problem...could it be that the backbone model doesn't match the server response but then that should trigger a backbone error not a jquery error

Answer (score 4):

Ahhhh - Programming can be so irritating sometimes. Finally figured this out - thanks for everyones help but it was a simple coffeescript compiling issue

So before I had

```
$.ajaxPrefilter ( (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) -> 
 options.url = "#{ API_URL }" + options.url
)
```

which compile to return both options.url and $.ajaxPrefilter. For whatever reason, Jquery was picking up the options.url as a [DataTypes argument](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/) on the ajaxPrefilter function. The solution was to return false:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter \
  (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) -> 
    options.url = "#{ API_URL }" + options.url
    no
```

which gives the correct compiled version

```
return $.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
  options.url = ("" + API_URL) + options.url;
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Wow I've been banging my head for hours with the same issue, thanks